# Can I Improve vassal relations to king as Marshal?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I'm wondering if it's possible to, as Marshal, improve relations between vassals of my faction and the king.  As it is, all but a few vassals have very negative relation levels with him and they're all leaving in droves.  Is there a way to exert any control over this as Marshal or as a vassal?  I'm not looking to replace the king just yet..  I'm also using the Diplomacy mod in case there is something in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the the diplomacy mod, but the only way I know of to make peace between two members of the same faction is done by talking to your spouse and asking if there's anything to improve your standing in the kingdom.  Every once in a while, they'll offer a mission where you can go make peace between two lords in your kingdom (hopefully one of them will be the king).

Another indirect way of improving relations is getting your king to grant that vassal a fief.  You can lend your weight behind a lord by talking to them and choosing the option of supporting them in their claim to some fief.  If the king does grant them the land I'd imagine that their relationships will improve.  Keep in mind, however, that this will alienate the opposing faction.  Politics in Caldera is very murky and unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to Spartacus, if you meet with them on the field, a castle or a town, you can say "Do you have any tasks for me"? Completing them for the lord will grant you relation points with them and SOMETIMES just accepting the quest gives you relation points.

The lazy way out to get your relation to 0 with them is to just wait for a while, aspfter a while they'll forget the things you did to them and slowly your relation with them will go from the negatives to 0, no higher.